# Java redirect the sysout of a class in a jar

Tags: java, redirect, jar, system.out

I would like to redirect/hide the sysout generated by the following code :

```
Tools tool = new ToolsImpl();
HashCode hash = tool.computeHashCodes(dir);
```

The difficult part is : **the method computeHashCodes is stored in a jar**.

I've tried the following code :

```
PrintStream printStreamOriginal=System.out;
System.out.println("sysout deactivated");

System.setOut(new PrintStream(new OutputStream() {
   public void write(int b) {}
}));

System.out.println("Text to delete");

Tools tool = new ToolsImpl();
HashCode hash = tool.computeHashCodes(dir);

System.setOut(printStreamOriginal);
System.out.println("sysout reactivated");
```

The "*text to delete*" is indeed deleted, but the sysout generated by the ".*computeHashCodes*" is not. Does someone know how to hide this sysout ?

Thx in advance, 
Mike

Comment: You could try if there is anything going through your new System.out stream by printing out something in the `write()`... If there is nothing there, computeHashCodes is not printing out over System.out

Comment: Hi, I've already tried this, and indeed nothing was printed out of the write() method. The method computeHashCodes() in the jar just didn't use any "System.out.println", but it used the [Java Logger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html) instead. Have a look at my answer below, I described how I managed to avoid displaying the sysout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone, I finally managed to avoid displaying the sysout.

When *Magodiez* advised me to find how the output was done, I thought I couldn't do that because I didn't have access to the source code ; but then I realised I just had to decompile the code.

So I decompiled it with [Java Decompiler](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui), and then I saw how the output was done :

```
LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, str2);
```

Then I resolved my problem by using the following line :

```
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("log.tools").setLevel(Level.SEVERE);
```

It is actually what I really wanted, now only the SEVERE messages will be printed on the sysout.

Thanks again !

Answer (score 2):

The code may be writing to System.err instead.

Try the same exercise but with System.err instead of System.out.

Comment: Hi, I've just tried it but it still isn't working (the sysout generated is categorized as "INFORMATION", that's why I used System.out). Thx anyway :)

Comment: So the basic problem is actually not that you want output swallowed, but that you want some specific log statement ignored.  Try reconfiguring your logging backend instead.

Answer (score 1):

your solution works fine when using `System.out`, so I'm guessing that the code you want to "block" doesn't use `System.out` for the output. Try to find how the output is done, so you can "block" it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick answer ! I can use the classes in the jar, but unfortunately I don't have access to the source code, so I don't know how the output is done. But couldn't it be the fact that the class is in a separate jar that causes the sysout to be displayed ?

Comment: Nop, just tried, and works fine with the System.out in an external .jar
make sure it's not displayed with System.err like said Thorbjørn

Answer (score 1):

See here:

[Writing to jars](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/CreateJarfile.htm)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.jar.JarEntry;
import java.util.jar.JarOutputStream;
import java.util.jar.Manifest;

public class CreateJarFile {
  public static int BUFFER_SIZE = 10240;
  protected void createJarArchive(File archiveFile, File[] tobeJared) {
    try {
      byte buffer[] = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
      // Open archive file
      FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(archiveFile);
      JarOutputStream out = new JarOutputStream(stream, new Manifest());

      for (int i = 0; i < tobeJared.length; i++) {
        if (tobeJared[i] == null || !tobeJared[i].exists()
            || tobeJared[i].isDirectory())
          continue; // Just in case...
        System.out.println("Adding " + tobeJared[i].getName());

        // Add archive entry
        JarEntry jarAdd = new JarEntry(tobeJared[i].getName());
        jarAdd.setTime(tobeJared[i].lastModified());
        out.putNextEntry(jarAdd);

        // Write file to archive
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(tobeJared[i]);
        while (true) {
          int nRead = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
          if (nRead <= 0)
            break;
          out.write(buffer, 0, nRead);
        }
        in.close();
      }

      out.close();
      stream.close();
      System.out.println("Adding completed OK");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
      System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```